# Отображение текста из файла на экране

Tags: objective-c

Подскажите как прочитать файл и вывести его на экран в компонент `label`? Вот код, который сейчас у меня получился, но он выводит всегда `(null)`.

```
- (IBAction)listenText:(id)sender {
    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSData *databuffer;

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: @"/Users/admin/text.txt.txt"];
    if (file == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open file");
    }
    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", file];
    _labelText.stringValue = s;
    [file closeFile];
 }
```

Comment: вы понимаете, что ваш file это инстанс класса `NSFileHandler` и с ним еще что то надо делать, чтобы прочитать данные из файла. начните с прочтения документации https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilehandle

Comment: Спасибо огромное за предоставленную информацию. Очень помогло. Впредь буду сразу читать документацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
- (IBAction)listenText:(id)sender {
    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSData *databuffer;

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: @"/Users/admin/text.txt"];
    databuffer = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: @"/Users/admin/text.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]);

    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: @"/Users/admin/text.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    _labelText.stringValue = s;
    [file closeFile];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень простой способ чтения файла:

```
NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/admin/text.txt"];
NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```